# Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, ftp, php-5.4

I am trying to do a form that upload a few fields, and 3 images. The images will be uploaded via FTP, there is a problem connecting to ftp with ftp_connect() when the php is uploaded to remote server. It couldn't connect to server when the php is in the shared host. But when the php is in the localhost, it display no error. I am now trying to make this work on Localhost and ftp_put the images into the remote server first, to isolate the error.
At the moment i am getting this error.

```
Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 69
```

Which is this  `ftp_put($login,"abc.info/$photo",$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],FTP_ASCII)`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
include 'Agentftpconnect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}


if ($_POST)
{
 //get form data



 $Listingname = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Listingname']));
 $Location = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Location']));
 $nobed = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['nobed']));
 $zip = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['zip']));
 $price = ($_POST['price']);


 if (!$Listingname||!$nobed||!$Location||!$zip||!$price)
    die ("Please fill out all fields"); 
    else 



    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
    {


if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] !== "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] !== "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] !== "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] !== "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] !== "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] !== "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] > 400000))
die("File is not correct");

else{

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    if (file_exists("abc.info/rent" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]))
      {
      die($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " already exists please add another file, or change the name ");
      }

    else

      {
        $photo=$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
      ftp_put($login,"abc.info/$photo",$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],FTP_ASCII) or die("Can not upload");
      echo "Stored in: " . "abc.info/rent/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
      }
    }
}



}

    {
      $photo0=$_FILES["file"]["name"][0];
        $photo1=$_FILES["file"]["name"][1];
         $photo2=$_FILES["file"]["name"][2];
       $username=$_SESSION['username'];

           //register into database
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Listing (username,Listingname,Location,nobed,zip,price,pic1,pic2,pic3) VALUES 
                ('$username','$Listingname','$Location','$nobed','$zip','$price','$photo0','$photo1','$photo2');") or die(mysqli_error());


            echo "Listing Added";
    }        

       }





else
{

?>

<form action="Submitlisting8.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
Listing Name:<br />
<input type='text' name='Listingname'><p />
Location:<br />
<input type='text' name='Location'><p />
Number of Beds:<br />
<input type='test' name='nobed'><p />
Zip:<br />
<input type='text' name='zip'><p />
Price:<br />
<input type='text' name='price'><p />


<label for="file">Pic1(File must be exceed 4mb):</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]"><br>
<label for="file">Pic2(File must be exceed 4mb):</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]"><br>
<label for="file">Pic3(File must be exceed 4mb):</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]"><br>
<br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="agentaccount.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Back to Account">
</form>

<?php

}



?>
```

FTPconnect

```
<?php
$ftp_user_name='name';
$ftp_user_pass='pass';
$connection = 'ftp.abc.info';

$connect = ftp_connect($connection) or die("Couldn't connect to $connection"); 
$login=ftp_login($connect, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if(!$login)
{
    die("But failed at login Attempted to connect to $connection for user $ftp_user_name....");
}


?>
```

Comment: Where does `$login` come from?

Comment: I just edited the question, included my ftpconnect php, $login is from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ftp_put()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) requires a valid resource which is obtained by using [`ftp_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php). If you are seeing this error message your call to `ftp_connect()` failed. You need to obtain a valid resource with `ftp_connect()`, and if you can't, you need to figure out what is causing your script not to connect to the remote host as that is the root cause of your problem.

To prevent your script from failing you should wrap your attempt to FTP in an `if` statement that checks to see if `ftp_connect()` connected successfully:

```
if (($resource = ftp_connect($host)) !== false) {
    // do FTP stuff
}
```

Comment: I tried to replace the $login, with $connect from the ftpconnect php( i just added in the question above), It gives me another error Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in, not sure how i should fix this problem

Comment: Thanks!I think i managed to upload it onto the remote server, just a problem that it doesn't display the picture when i type in the url. But i will try to figure it out. Thanks for the help!